# MongoDB Optimizing FindAndModify or Find + Sort

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

Running MongoDB, I am trying to queue a three column key lookup (a,b,c) with priority rank (d). I have a query like (pymongo syntax):

```
collection.find({'a':'foo','b':'bar','c':'baz'}, sort = [('d', -1)] )
```

With a compound index (a+1,b+1,c+1,d-1) running an explain shows full table scan and a BasicCursor.

With a single index on d, explain shows d index alone being used.

For a large table, what I really want is to use the compound index. How can I make this work?

INDEX_INFORMATION: 
{u'*id*': {u'key': [(u'_id', 1)], u'v': 1},
 u'color_1_level_1_in_progress_1_Ranking_-1': {u'key': [(u'color',
    1),
   (u'level', 1),
   (u'in_progress', 1),
   (u'Ranking', -1)],
  u'v': 1}}

```
EXPLAIN ON A FIND+SORT QUERY
db.coll.find({'level' : {'$in' : [0,1,2]}, 'in_progress' : 0, 'color' : {'$in' : ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green]} },  sort = [('Ranking', -1)] ).explain()

OUTPUT ON EXPLAIN
OperationFailure: database error: too much data for sort() with no index.  add an index or specify a smaller limit


THE QUEUEING QUERY I CARE ABOUT OPTIMIZING
coll.find_and_modify(
  query = {'level' : {'$in' : [0,1,2]}, 'in_progress' : 0, 'color' : {'$in' : ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green']} },
  sort = {'Ranking' : -1},                                                                                                                                                                             
  update = {'$set': {'in_progress': 1}} 
)
```

Note that when I add an index on the sort field 'Ranking', the explain returns that the Ranking index is being used. But the compound index is never used and performance is very slow on a 1.5 MM document test corpus.

Comment: Could you post db.collection.getIndexes(), the queries, and the output of explain()?

Comment: Yes, but I'll need some time. Should be up by tomorrow morning.

Comment: I should follow up that, after altering the query spec to use no logical '$in' or other operators and simply querying off specific values, mongo figured out to use the index. BUT! It appears not to be using the index for the sort operation, rather preferring to scan all docs matching the query. Weird!

Comment: I am having this exact same problem...  I'll let you know if I find anything

Comment: I think that $in is equivalent to performing separate queries for each element in the $in array. If you use two $in operators, each with 3 elements, that's equivalent to 3*3 = 9 separate indexed queries. I can potentially see how the query optimizer might decide that a table scan is faster.

Comment: Right. The big efficiency problem here now, having removed my $in's, seems to be not using the compound index for the sort operation embedded within the findandmodify. Sort of a drag for using mongo for a queue.

Answer (score 2):

There's a way to force specific index usage when doing query, called `hint`.

Just call it on a cursor:

```
cursor = collection.find({query-doc}).hint({index-fields})
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb indexing system is based on experimentation. Basically the query optimizer will run your queries using all the possible indexes and compare time for each. It will learn to use the best index for a given type of query.
From the docs on [query optimizer](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Query+Optimizer):

> when testing new plans, MongoDB executes multiple query plans in parallel.  As soon as one finishes, it terminates the other executions, and the system has learned which plan is good

If your collection is quite small, it is possible that the index chosen by the query optimizer is not what you think is the best. However it is the faster for this query and this collection.
When your collection grows up, maybe another index will fit better.

In your case, I think it is easier for mongo to scan all documents and then sort them with the index on d because you have very few documents.

Try to run the same query (several times to make learning efficient) against a collection with more documents (let say 1 million), you'll probably see that it will use the full index.

Thus, use oe hint won't be necessary (it won't harm though). My advice : let mongo query optimizer do its job :-)

Comment: Thank you for the insight on how mongo determines query plans behind the scenes. Unfortunately, my test corpus has over 1.5 MM documents, and the query is still running a full table scan. I know that I can optimize a find() operation more crudely by limiting the result set or targeting only a range of ranking values in the query spec. However, this doesn't really help me out for optimizing a findAndModify query, which I need because this operation needs to lock the record atomically.